# Are there design guidelines for sizing vent/surge tanks?

Tags: aircraft-design, fuel-systems, fuel-tanks

Could someone explain the sizing process of Vent/ Surge tank of Aircraft fuel system? I understand the Vent tank is to collect fuel overflow from the main fuel tanks. The reason could be due to Fuel thermal expansion or fuel over flow during manoeuvre or can be during pressure refueling.
The link 
[What is the capacity of the vent surge tank in an A320?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27211/what-is-the-capacity-of-the-vent-surge-tank-in-an-a320)
discuss about the fuel over flow by Thermal expansion. But can we size vent tank based on the pressure refueling fuel over flow? If so, for how long overflow to be considered? Though it is based on the Vent relief system and flow rates of specific aircraft, requesting any general guideline/ Reference for the design.
Thank you